# How to set width for YUI-data table dynamically based on max size of Column

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I have a YUI datatable and I am putting the following data in the table:

```
 {key:"name", label:"name", editor: nameChoiceEditor},
 {key:"group", label:"group", editor: groupChoiceEditor},
 {key:"colony", label:"colony", width: 210, editor: colonyChoiceEditor},
 ...
```

Here the `name` column's width is set to the maximum length of characters entered for that name, and the same with `group`. `colony`'s column width is set to 210 irrespective of the length of the data.

My problem is when the `name` column, having multiple words like "odaiah chitukuri", is showing in two lines like so:

```
  odaiah
  chitukuri
```

But when it is one word like "odaiahchitukuri" it is showing in a single line, meaning the column is adjusting to fit the word.

I should have the different words in sigle line. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the 'breaking' spaces replace with non-breaking spaces.

Try the following:

Change:

```
{key:"colony", label:"colony", width: 210, editor: colonyChoiceEditor},
```

To:

```
{key:"colony", label:"colony", width: 210, editor: colonyChoiceEditor
  formatter: function (el, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
    el.innerHTML = oData.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your looking for a solution that will always keep the words on a single line.. but generally speaking the datatable does a good job of spacing out the columns correctly based on the content inside.  In certain cases though I've definitely had to set the width of a column manually.  Here is an example for a column with class appicon:

```
.yui-skin-sam .yui-dt tbody td.appicon {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Bare in mind once the number of words in the column stretches past it's defined size, it will always move to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

In datatable column define :

- will be `width:100`
- not `width:"100px"`
- or `width:"100"`
- or `width:"100em"`

**Use width: 100**

like that then its working fine for me